# Display Post response data to template angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Usually we call `get` request to display the data to client side. Is there any way to display the response that we get when we perform `post` request ?

Process:
The user from client side post word and on the basis of word that is posted the `post` give response response as follows:

```
>0:{username:'patrick',userid:'3636363',position:'manager'}
>1:{username:'patrick1',userid:'3636364',position:'employee'}
>2:{username:'patrick2',userid:'3636365',position:'employee'}
```

I have used following way to post data
My html:

```
<form #search="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(search.value)">
<input type="text" name ="name" ngModel placeholder="name">
<button type="submit"> Search</button>
</form>
```

my component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent{
url='https://localhost:7292/api/';

constructor (private http:HttpClient){}

  onSubmit(data:string){
this.http.post(this.Url+'Employee?name='data.name,data).subscribe((result)=>{
   console.log(result)
  })
}
In console for result it shows:
>0:{username:'patrick',userid:'3636363',position:'manager'}
>1:{username:'patrick1',userid:'3636364',position:'employee'}
>2:{username:'patrick2',userid:'3636365',position:'employee'}
```

So I want to display `username,userid,position` to the template. How do i display the post response ?

Comment: Could you add template to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to store the response in a public or private class member like this:

```
export class HomeComponent{
constructor(){}

public result: string = '';

onSubmit(data:string){
this.http.post(this.Url+'Employee?name='data.name,data).subscribe((rslt:string)=>{
   this.result = rslt;
  })

}
```

and then in the template (HTML) you can access this property like this:

```
<div>{{result}}</div> /* Here you can see your result public variable of type string */
```

Comment: using `<div>{{result | json }}</div>` I was able to display the Json but to access individual property using  `<div>{{result.username}}</div>`  shows nothing. Is there anything that I am missing or do i need to use ngif  to get individual property since the response is in array and it has about 50 Array data.

Comment: *ngFor is your friend..

Comment: If the response is an array lets do an example:
  
   In Typescript file we define an array of strings called 'myAnimals'
    `const myAnimals = [{kind:'cat'}, {kind:'bird'}, {kind: 'crocodile'}];`

in HTML file we can use ngFor directive like this in order to display our 3 animals
`<div 
*ngFor="let animal of animals"
>
{{animals.kind}}
</div>`

The expected output on the screen will be ->
                *cat 
'bird', 'crocodile

Answer (score 0):

I think the optimal solution for this would be to create an object with the properties you will be displaying from the response, (userName, userId, position);
When your post request returns, create the object with the values or set the object properties with said values (once validated) if already constructed. You can then use the object properties and angular's interpolation syntax to display the values to the user. You can also conditionally render the sections with ngIf directive and only display the values when they are set to something other than null/default values/safestate.

Edit.
Also you should add a error catch to your http request to handle non success responses. You can add an error msg display here